# Force base size of images via css possible

Tags: html, css

i am grabbing images from an xml feed that are usually 320*240 .. but sadly, sometimes the images are just 320*239 or 320*238.

When I use these images now with my responsive Layout, it messes up the layout. The Image below that wrong scaled image is still fine, but the images besides that wrong scaled image are pushed two rows down.

Is there any way that i can force the BASE size of the images to be the desired one to avoid this problem? I had tried already to work with min-height to avoid that problem, usually the images are a bit scaled up / down when the resolution is changed. So working with these values is not really an option.

Images are not saved on my server, just hotlinked, so i would need some kind of way to just tell the browser to ignore the real image size and just accepps the size i tell him somehow what the size I want that he 'think' the image has.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Kindly, Sascha

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if there's a way to always get a minimum native image resolution, which isn't possible. You can't ask for more data than what exists.

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly, have you tried adding an `!important` css declaration to enforce the desired presentation of the relevant images?

Comment: maybe with some html/css we can try helping you..

Comment: Show your htm/css. You should probably wrap your images in container divs which have a min-height.